# how to run scheduled task ,after resume from sleep,only if computer was sleeping at the time of schedule

Tags: backup, suspend, cron, resume

i have a cron backup job set up, but i would like it to run after resume from sleep, if my computer was asleep at the scheduled time.

example: 
backup script runs every night at 2:00.
often i put my computer to sleep before night.
at morning i start my computer.
i would like to run the backup script as soon as possible,after resume.

is there any simple way to make it work,
without making double backups if i don't put my computer to sleep ?
(somehow the cron/ or any other scheduler must know and remember it didnt do the scheduled task in the specified time and execute it as soon as possible)

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anacron can you what you are asking and is available in the Ubuntu repo's. From the man page:

*Anacron is used to execute commands periodically, with a frequency specified in days. Unlike cron(8), it does not assume that the machine is running continuously. Hence, it can be used on machines that aren't running 24 hours a day, to control regular jobs as daily, weekly, and monthly jobs.*

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/anacron.8.html

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct for the question posed. Anacron itself is just a daily cron job that will get missed because the laptop is usually in suspend at 2am. Anacron will also run shortly after a reboot, but in the sleeping laptop case, that might not happen for weeks or months. If there is a feature of Anacron that allows it to handle suspended but not rebooted machines, that feature is not described in the man page.